# How to connect my CSS file in Yii2?

Tags: php, css, yii2, assets

I'm trying to connect my CSS file into my project. For this I do:

In /web/css/ I've created `my-custom.css` file. Later in /views/my_folder/_form.php I've added these lines:

```
use \app\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
```

but it still does not work. I'm new in Yii2, so maybe I do something wrong. Any suggestions what I need to do else?

Answer (score 2):

This might be helful to you

1) Open Frontend folder

2) In that open  assets Folder

3)Open Appasset.php

then write

```
public $css = [
        'css/my-custom.css'
    ];
```

Or else Try this in your view file

```
$this->registerCssFile("http://example.com/css/my-custom.css", [
    'depends' => [BootstrapAsset::className()]       
]);
```

Comment: have you checked base path ?

Is it like  public $basePath = '@webroot';

    public $baseUrl = '@web';
In appasset.php

Comment: yes, public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

Comment: Is it Worked for you??